# Can SQLite import only specified fields from a large textfile?

Tags: sqlite, etl, database-schema

I'm trying to work with a 2.5Gb text file, which comprises 293 fields in a tab-delimited extract.

Here is a short [sample](http://www.steveandglo.com/maps/code/short.txt) of the first 2 rows + header. I'm only concerned with the first few fields (lang,Titel,lat,lon,types).

**What is the fastest way to load only certain fields from a textfile into SQLite?**

I can't open the textfile in Notepad, Excel or Word as it's so large, so I can't delete the unnecessary fields manually.

In SQLite3 I have defined the target table including all 293 fields. To import the data I'm using:

```
.separator "\t"
.import textfile.txt tablename
```

This means I need to load in the entire table before I can drop the unnecessary fields. Is there a faster way?

Thanks

Comment: Might honestly just be a simple script (with a nice method of extracting said fields) -- piped so the entire file isn't loaded at once. Just use a transaction and commit in batches or once at end. Also might be better no *not* use WAL-mode during the import.

Comment: FYI I ended up writing a Python script to drop the fields in the text file, before loading the smaller file into SQLite. I'd still be interested in finding the code to do this directly in SQLite if it's possible

Comment: @pst if you want to add your comments as an Answer, I'll mark it as resolved since it seems the best workaround

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your solution, but I was going to suggest using regular expression to clean up your data file first.